# Is "defeating the object" an error in speech?

Tags: idioms

I've been hearing this phrase used from time to time in my family when someone does something opposed to a goal that they want to achieve. Is it some sort of error? I can't find a source or explanation for the phrase. "Defeating the purpose" or even "defeating the objective" would make sense to be, but the **object**?

Comment: It is not an idiom and it is not an error - the phrase has its literal meaning. If you can give a few examples, that will help.

Comment: Look at https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/44405/definition-of-the-object-of-the-exercise